# How to use scalatest to check that certain events happen in a particular order?

Tags: events, scala, scalatest

I need to test that my library processes certain (user-defined) events in the proper order. Currently, I'm doing something very simple. I create a buffer and let each of the events append a different value to it:

```
val buf = new collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int];
val ev1 = () => { buf += 1; }
val ev2 = () => { buf += 2; }
//
// ... library runs the events ...
// 
// check that ev2 ocurred before ev1
buf should be (ArrayBuffer(2, 1))
```

Is there a better and clearer way?

**Update:** Meanwhile I created a [tiny toolkit](https://gist.github.com/ppetr/5188419) that helps me with the tests. The main class `Event` allows to wrap computations and functions and registers when a computation occurred with respect to other events. I have only a little insight into *scalatest* so I don't know how to integrate it better - if you know, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's almost the same, but you could make your code a bit cleaner. If you need to test event order multiple times you could define a trait like this:

```
trait EventOrderTester {
  val buf = ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
  def ev(order: Int): () => Unit = () => buf += order
  lazy val expected = buf.sorted
}
```

Then you can define tests like this:

```
"my test" in new EventOrderTester {

  x.addListener1(ev(2))
  x.addListener2(ev(1))

  //
  // ... library runs the events ...
  // 
  // check that listener2 ocurred before listener1
  buf should be(expected)
}
```